# I need my function to return the GCD of the given inputs using LISP while loop and Euclids Algorithm my output I am getting is 0

Tags: elisp

(defun gcd (n m)
"Returns the gcd of any two inputed values."
(let ((dividend n) (divisor m) (remainder 1))
(cond
((> n m)
(gcd m n))
((< n m)
(while (/= remainder 0)
(setq remainder (% dividend divisor))
(setq dividend divisor)
(setq divisor remainder))
(princ divisor)))))

(gcd 12 18)
00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with your code really. However, I don't think your approach is the best, if we're considering the lisp language. It'd be better to write a recursive function: that's much shorter and - imho - more beautiful.

```
(defun gcd (n m)
  (cond ((< n m) (gcd m n))
        ((= m 0) n)
        (t (gcd m (% n m)))))
```

The main point is the concept of tail recursion, which actually makes a fair loop instead of this recursive function, so you won't get any stack-overflow errors.